# Is it possible to use the device passcode as a form of validation in your private app?

Tags: ios, security

I would like to enable the device passcode and encrypt the data on the device when it's locked. No big deal. However, in the app I'm developing there is an internal admin section that will require another validation step to perform actions. Is it possible to reuse the device passcode in the app without having to manage two passwords separately?

I know there is no way I can get access to the passcode, but even something like YES or NO returned if the passcode's match? I guess that's opening the door to some brute-force methods though?

Any feedback regrading this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As my knowledge apple is crazy for there pass code so there is now way you can do that. but your client can do one thing he can setup pass code and keep same pass code, and you can validate on your side but there is no access @ all to passcode.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't provide developers with direct access to any notifications when the device is locked/unlocked. You can add your own security within the app for the on-disk data stored by your app, have a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) (specifically, the "Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption" section).

Alternatively, you can use an in-app passcode to protect your data. An OSS component I have used recently is [AppinViewController](https://github.com/Alterplay/APPinViewController).

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses the passcode (wich is not limited to 4-digits!) to encrypt the data on the phone.
You won't be able/allowed to use/test the passcode.

Related [White Paper by Apple](http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_Feb14.pdf) (See page 10):

> By setting up a device passcode, the user automatically enables Data
>   Protection. **iOS supports four-digit and arbitrary-length alphanumeric
>   passcodes.** In addition to unlocking the device, a passcode provides
>   the entropy for encryption keys, which are not stored on the device.
>   This means an attacker in possession of a device can’t get access to
>   data in certain protection classes without the passcode.